# Android Tell Service Not To Start Until Other Service Completes

Tags: android, service

I have two background services in my application that are scheduled at regular intervals by the AlarmManager.  The intervals are different for each service.  I would like to run one service every two minutes, and the other service every 15 mins.

**How can I prevent them from running at the same time?**

If one Service is called while the other is running, I want it to run immediately after the first one finishes.

Comment: any reason that you don't want to start the second service from the first?

Comment: Shedule only first and start second one from first, just before it will stop doing it job ...

Comment: @mfrankli i think the cause is too much coffe and dead line ....

Comment: I was thinking about creating a service to manage a queue of services but I'm worried the child services will cause the manager service to be knocked out of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to run one service every two minutes, and the other service every 15 mins.
>
> How can I prevent them from running at the same time?

You combine them into one service, running every N minutes, that does the less-frequent work every Mth time.

Comment: How would I track what nth time it is being called? Would I use a variable in the global Application class, a shared preference, or database variable? Does it really matter which one I choose? It would just be a number mod 15.

Comment: @zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz: "Would I use a variable in the global Application class, a shared preference, or database variable?" -- probably something persistent, particularly if these are `IntentServices`, as your process may go away between events. I'd lean towards a `SharedPreference`.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule only one service which you want to start first and when this service finish start another service in `onDestroy` of first service.

Comment: One service is scheduled to run every 2 minutes the other is scheduled to run every 15 mins.